Pipeline flagging build as failed when a warning is printed to the output stream
I have an azure-pipelines.yml file which runs a django server.
Now, I had set SET GLOBAL sql_mode = ''; in MySQL.
So when the django server starts its throws a warning which is getting printed to the output stream.
##[error]Bash wrote one or more lines to the standard error stream.
##[error]System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
?: (mysql.W002) MySQL Strict Mode is not set for database connection 'default'
    HINT: MySQL's Strict Mode fixes many data integrity problems in MySQL, such as data truncation upon insertion, by escalating warnings into errors. It is strongly recommended you activate it. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/databases/#mysql-sql-mode

Finishing: Build and Test

This is causing the build to report as failed but the server re-starts and the site works fine.

What should be done for the pipeline to ignore this particular warning and not flag it as failed ?
